# Flutter: How to implement delete capability to image in Carousel

Tags: dart, flutter

I've been trying to find a way to add a Dismissible or Gesturedetector to the images in a carousel (carousel_pro), so a user can swipe or press to delete a given image, but no success!
Would appreciate any hints or ideas on how to achieve this.

```js
AspectRatio(
  aspectRatio: 0.9,
  child: Carousel(
    images: aData.images.map((url) {
      return GestureDetector(
        child: CachedNetworkImageProvider(url),
        onTap: () {});
    }).toList(),
    dotSize: 4.0,
    dotSpacing: 15.0,
    dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
    dotColor: Colors.red,
    autoplay: false,
  ),
),
```

This throws an error: The argument type 'CachedNetworkImageProvider' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'.

Comment: did you tried the tap method from GestureDetector?

Comment: I did. Please see edit, where I added GestureDetector.

Answer (score 0):

this is the way to use CahedImage in Flutter

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        placeholder: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        imageUrl:
            'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
      ),
```

so, Your code will be

```
 return GestureDetector(
    child:CachedNetworkImage(
        placeholder: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        imageUrl:
            'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
      ),
    onTap: () {});
})
```

Comment: Ok, thank u. So essentially it's just replacing CachedNetworkImageProvider with CachedNetworkImage. Not sure why I was using CachedNetworkImageProvider (used it in other projects), but I'll try it out and see if it creates other issues.

Comment: Try it and let me know

Comment: Well I finally had a chance to try it and threw this runtime error: The following assertion was thrown building Carousel(dirty, state: CarouselState#6e9c6):
type 'GestureDetector' is not a subtype of type 'ImageProvider<dynamic>'

Comment: And then I removed GestureDetector and now the error is: The following assertion was thrown building Carousel(dirty, state: CarouselState#617f8):
 type 'CachedNetworkImage' is not a subtype of type 'ImageProvider<dynamic>'. So now I remember why I was using CachedNetworkImageProvider in my other projects, it's that carousel_pro won't accept any other type of cache providers.

Comment: So, still don't know how to be able to delete images directly in Carousel. Anyone?

Comment: if you're using something like List to build carrousels you need to remove item binded to your caroussel then call setState(){}. Since you have not  provided  code, I can't really help you with specific details

Comment: Actually I provided the code which shows how the carousel is populated, at the top of this post. For me to be able to remove a given item from the list I must somehow be able to get it's id by selecting it in the carousel. That's why I tried wrapping the items in a gesturedetector. But that doesn't work as we've seen.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to remove item from screen, (not deleting from database), you need to wrap gestureDetector into an if statement.

```
class YourClass extends StatefullWidget{
  boolean showCaroussel = true;
.......
return  showCaroussel ? GestureDetector(
child:CachedNetworkImage(
    placeholder: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    imageUrl:
        'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
  ),
onTap: () {
 setState((){
showCaroussel  = !showCaroussel ;
});
}) ;
}): Container();
```

Hope it Heps..